# for loop not working after while loop in php

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

For loop is not working after while loop. If I write for loop first and then write while loop than while loop will not work. But I don't understand why it occurs.

```
$ini = 101;
$end = 103;

while($ini<$end){
    echo $ini." I am while\n";
    $ini++;
}

echo "\n\n";

for($ini; $ini<$end; $ini++){
    echo $ini."I am for loop\n";
}

echo "\n\n";

do {
    echo "$ini I am do while";
} 
while($ini<$end);

?>
```

Comment: Well `$ini` is not `<` `$end` so it shouldn't enter that. The `$ini++` increases that value.

Comment: What's your thought process on the program flow? Did you assume `$ini` to get reset after each loop?

Comment: Generally you would have `for($ini = 0;`

Comment: Per your update it seems you don't understand what `$ini++` does. That increases the value of the variable by 1 value. The original value no longer exists after that call. You may want to be using a second variable.

Answer (score 1):

You just want to practice **PHP Loops** I guess.

Remember to use different variables or initialize/reset used variables.

```
// while loop
$ini = 101;
$end = 103;
while($ini<$end){
    echo $ini." I am while\n";
    $ini++;
}
echo "\n\n";

// for loop
$ini = 101;  // initialize/reset
$end = 103;  // initialize/reset
for($ini; $ini<$end; $ini++){
    echo $ini."I am for loop\n";
}
echo "\n\n";

// do-while loop
$ini = 101;  // initialize/reset
$end = 103;  // initialize/reset
do {
    echo "$ini I am do while";
} 
while($ini<$end);
```

P.S. `?>` is not necessary to add.